# What do the C operators "&=" and "|=" do?

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded

I've been working trying to read some C code and I've found some operators that I don't know:

What's the use of `&=` and `|=` operators when used for microprocessors programming?

Comment: I don't believe those operators are any different between micros and other platforms.

Comment: For the complete masterclass http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354138/is-there-a-defined-evaluation-order-for-and

Comment: this type of question belongs on stackoverflow

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These statements are equivalent:

`x = x & 0x01;`

`x &= 0x01;`

It means to perform a bitwise operation with the values on the left and right-hand side, and then assign the result to the variable on the left, so a bit of a short form.  If you're not familiar with bitwise operations, I suggest you start getting familiar with those first - the `&` being a bitwise AND and the `|` being a bitwise OR.

Hope that helps!

Comment: "A compound assignment of the form  E1 op= E2 differs from the simple assignment expression E1 = E1 op (E2) only in that the lvalue E1 is evaluated only once."

Answer (score 5):

`&=` is `and equals`, `|=` is `or equals`. These perform bit-wise operations with the left hand and right hand arguments, and assign the result into the left hand side.

Comment: This definition may look a bit weird for someone unfamilliar with the language. It could be interpreted as "(foo == 0 |= 1)" would be a valid condition.

Comment: @Júlio Souza - how could you interpret it that way? how would you assign (0|1) into 0? assigning a value into a constant is nonsensical, and should be a strong clue that the construct 0 |= 1 is not valid.

Comment: It's a valid interpretation if you say that the `=` means `is equal to` (that's what `equals` means!). `==` means `equals`, `=` means `assign ... to`.

Comment: @Stevenvh - either way, (foo == 0) |= 1 doesn't make any sense, and neither does foo == (0 |= 1)